# Can fallen metal fascia be reinstalled?

Tags: roof, siding

I noticed that this fell off my house last night. How can I reinstall it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the piece to the left might be preparing to come off as well.

Comment: The original questions (two, really) were highly subjective. I've reformulated to salvage.

Answer (score 2):

The longer you wait, the chances of more damage increase. The row of soffit vents look like it's sagging downward and could rip off with a good wind.

As far as doing it yourself, it depends on how comfortable you are working on a roof and a ladder. You'd need to position a ladder on the first floor roof and extend it to the second floor roof and brace/secure it, and then do the repair work.. This is not ideal working conditions for the faint of heart and might be better of left to the pros.

Answer (score 0):

**Project Description**

This kind of fascia slips up under the roof edge flange and is attached mostly along the underside, though one or more nails are often used at end joints. This minimizes "oil canning", rippling in the vertical face which can be very conspicuous in certain light. The fascia also helps hold the outer edge of the soffit, which is just tacked during installation.

**Tools and Materials**

- Hammer
- White corrosion-resistant or aluminum nails - about 4d ("four penny", 1-1/2")
- Needle-nose pliers (optional, may prevent sore thumbs)

**Repair Process**

1. Tack up any very loose or displaced fascia panels along the underside of the wooden subfascia with nails set in the channels where they'll be concealed by the fascia cover.
2. Reattach the remaining (loose) fascia cover by pressing it against the wooden subfascia and sliding it upward, then putting nails in new holes along the underside.
3. Reinstall the fallen fascia wrap in the same manner. Be sure it fits tight to the surfaces behind to prevent denting.
4. Add nails in the original holes on the vertical face for best appearance. Drive extra nails if anything feels loose in these areas.